# Grails 2.4.4 removing all items from a hasmany String relationship

Tags: grails

I have a User class that hasMany organizations, and organizations are String UIDs.

```
class User implements Serializable {
  ...
  List organizations
  static hasMany = [organizations: String]
  ...
}
```

To update an User instance, I need to remove all the Strings from "organizations" before adding what the updated uids, but it doesn't work. The same organizations are resaved into the collection after I delete them and save the User instance.

I tried many ways:

```
// 1
user.organizations.clear()

// 2
def orgsToDelete = [] // this is to avoid concurrent modification exception
orgsToDelete += user.organizations
orgsToDelete.each { orguid ->
   user.removeFromOrganizations(orguid)
}
```

After any of 1 or 2, the user.organizations is empty, but when I do:

```
user.save(flush:true)
```

I get the same organizations that where before the clear/removeFromOrganizations

I can't do user.organizations.each { it.delete() } because the items are not domain classes but Strings.

Another weird thing is I have a custom validator to check if the collection has any items, and it seems it doesn't gets any errors, event the organizations is empty, this is my validator:

```
organizations validator: { val, obj ->
  if (obj.organizations.size() == 0) return false
  return true
}
```

When I do this on the controller update action, it says hasErrors() == false

```
if (userInstance.hasErrors())
{
   println "has errors"
   respond userInstance.errors, view:'edit'
   return
}
```

Any ideas?

Here is the controller: https://github.com/ppazos/cabolabs-ehrserver/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/com/cabolabs/security/UserController.groovy#L199-L237

Answer (score 0):

Use your own domain class instead of `String` as collection's elements, like:

```
class Organization {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [ User ]
}
```

then you should be able to properly remove the children by

```
user.organisations.clear()
user.save()
```

The reason for the behaviour you a facing is, that the String instances are mapped to a table which has no back-refs to the `user`. That leads to the situation, that the records in that `string` table are not actually removed and are loaded upon the next database call.

Comment: The mapping table for the strings, "user_organizations", has a user_id, but I notice it is not set as FK to the "user" table. Let me rephrase your answer because this might be a Grails bug: it is not possible to remove items from a hasMany String relationship?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. In Hibernate (not in Grails) `Strings` are not really supposed to be a domain object

Comment: I understand that Strings are not domain objects. But I'm pointing to the fact that Grails supports this feature of declaring and adding Strings to a hasMany relationship, but it doesn't seem to support removing items from the relationship. If "adding" is supported I would normally expect "removing" to also be supported. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you need to have an array of strings in your domain model, the best way would be to use a noSQL DB, as no RDBMS has a support for for them. Thus, hibernate/GORM provide only a work-around for such aggregation which is not that elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your project code and you have the DataSource bad set. You are using a H2 memory BBDD, but using the MySQL driver instead (in the development environment). It doesnt look good. Set it properly, and try again.

I have test your model, and used:

```
user.organizations.clear()
```

without any problems, even using your custom validator.

In other hand you should use a Service instead for all the business logic, not a controller. Because a service is transactional by default.

Here are the changes I did, and works:

```
//   List organizations = []
   static hasMany = [organizations: String] 

   static mapping = {
      password column: '`password`'
      // organizations lazy: false
   }
```

Removing List organizations. Using the H2 datasource with this config at DataSource development environment:

```
       dbCreate = "create-drop" 
       url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
       username = "sa"
       password = ""
```

And this code works like a charm:

```
   def clearOrganizationFromUser(){

      //creating user with timestamp
      User user = new User(username: 'username' + new Date(), password: 'password', email: 'email@email.es', accountExpired: false, accountLocked: false,
         passwordExpired: false)
      List<String> organizations = []
      10.times{
         organizations << "organization $it"
      }

      organizations.each{ String organization ->
         user.addToOrganizations(organization)
      }

      user.save()
      println "Organizations after saving: ${user.organizations}"

      //Its not neccesary but I did it for showing that organization are persisted in DDBB
      User newUserFromDDBB = User.get(user.id)

      //deleting organization
      newUserFromDDBB.organizations.clear()
      newUserFromDDBB.save()

      println "---> Organizations after deleting: ${newUserFromDDBB.organizations}"

   }
```

Hope It works. If do, please mark as solved.

Comment: it only sets the url with H2, then it is reset to the mysql:url url = "jdbc:mysql://$host:$port/$dbName" it is working ok, but I can comment the first url set.

Comment: I can send you a project demo working. Maybe it helps

Comment: Please do, I would like to check the differences, because I tested the .clear() and wasn't working for me. Do you want to send a PR? just to see the diffs on github. Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, I think the issue might be because I'm using MySQL instead of H2 for dev & prod, it may have something to do with how H2 manages FKs, because after the .clear() I got the organization strings again under user.organizations. Did you saw in the H2 console if the organization strings were deleted from the user_organizations table? On my DB that wasn't happening.

Comment: No, sorry but at the end of the code I am querying by the id for a new instance of user, and there is no organizations, so I guess they are deleted